# EWS won't work in Powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

So I have set up to identical Exchange webservice examples:

C# version running as a console application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var es = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2)
        {
            TraceEnabled = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = true,
            Url = new Uri("https://mail.myServer.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")
        };

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;

        var inboxId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
        Folder inboxFolder = null;
        try
        {
            inboxFolder = Folder.Bind(es, inboxId);
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        if (inboxFolder == null)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("FAILED");
            return;
        }
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Total stuff: [{0}]", inboxFolder.TotalCount);
        Console.In.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Powershell version:

```
clear
# Load EWS Managed API
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll";

$EWSService = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2010_SP2)
$EWSService.traceenabled = $true
$EWSService.UseDefaultCredentials = $true 
$EWSService.Url = New-Object Uri("https://mail.myServer.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $true };

$InboxID = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox)
Try {$InboxFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($EWSservice,$InboxID)}
Catch [Exception] {
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Both are running on the same machine, same user.  The console app connects and returns data.  The powershell version gets a very helpful message:

```
The request failed. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
```

Inspecting the exception does not give any additional infor.  Both versions are referencing the same EWS managed api.  Anyone have any ideas why this would be the case?

Comment: I'm not an expert at EWS, but that [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $true };
looks out of place.  I've only seen that used when AutoDiscover is being used to find the Exchange server, but you've got the server name already hard-coded in the URI.

Comment: From my readings of it's use, this is used for ignoring certificate errors when a server is using unsigned certificates.  Even if I am wrong about this, the code works in .NET and not in powershell so either way the callback shouldn't be the issue (and just to be sure I tried both).

Comment: I experienced the same issue today. I noticed that the behavior is different in standard Windows PowerShell console and SharePoint 2013 PowerShell console. In particular, the solution described [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/ad493b72-6465-450b-bd49-8f15675d7f53) worked for Windows PowerShell but not for SharePoint one.
Note the link seems to be broken and I pulled the page from Google cache.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the problem.

```
# Load EWS Managed API
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll";
```

That is not a Powershell Module.

I use Add-Type to load that .dll in my EWS scripts like this:

```
   Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll'
```

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestions.  Unfortunately when I tied this solution I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Per JohhnyJob's Message use

```
    ## Code From http://poshcode.org/624
## Create a compilation environment
$Provider=New-Object Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider
$Compiler=$Provider.CreateCompiler()
$Params=New-Object System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters
$Params.GenerateExecutable=$False
$Params.GenerateInMemory=$True
$Params.IncludeDebugInformation=$False
$Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.DLL") | Out-Null

$TASource=@'
  namespace Local.ToolkitExtensions.Net.CertificatePolicy{
    public class TrustAll : System.Net.ICertificatePolicy {
      public TrustAll() { 
      }
      public bool CheckValidationResult(System.Net.ServicePoint sp,
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert, 
        System.Net.WebRequest req, int problem) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
'@ 
$TAResults=$Provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource($Params,$TASource)
$TAAssembly=$TAResults.CompiledAssembly

## We now create an instance of the TrustAll and attach it to the ServicePointManager
$TrustAll=$TAAssembly.CreateInstance("Local.ToolkitExtensions.Net.CertificatePolicy.TrustAll")
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy=$TrustAll

## end code from http://poshcode.org/624
```

Instead of

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $true };
```